# React, Mobx. Looped component render due to state change

Tags: reactjs, state, mobx, mobx-react

Before rendering, my component should find out whether user authorized.

Function checkAuth( ) do this task.
While function does its work, state `isLoading` equal true. Before the end of its work, the function assigns state `isLoading` to false

While this state equal true, component renders loading animation.

When state equal false, component renders another content

My problem is that the component is looping to render over and over again. If I understand correctly, the state changes in the function `checkAuth()`, and component as observer reacts to this changing and re-renders itself. After rerender, the function `checkAuth()` starts again and so on in a circle.

I tried call this function inside useEffect and outside of this.
Nothing helped me.

I expecting:
function checkAuth() runs
state isLodaing assigns to true
component renders 
checkAuth continues to do its job
before end of function checkAuth, state isLoading assigns to false

component observes this
stop rendering 
start rendering another content: routes

Thank you very much for reading.

Component:

```
const AppRouter: FC = () => {
  const controller = useContext(ControllerContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    controller.checkAuth()

  })

  if (controller.appStore.getIsLoading) {
    console.log('loading');

    return (<Loading />);
  }

  else return (
    <div>routes</div>

    // <Routes>

    //   {/* Private routes for authorized user */}
    //   <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
    //     <Route element={<MainPageView />} path="/" />
    //     <Route element={<SettingsPage />} path="/settings" />
    //   </Route>

    //   {/* Public routes for unauthorized users */}
    //   <Route element={<UnauthorizedRoutes />}>
    //     <Route element={<LoginPage />} path="/login" />
    //     <Route element={<SignupPage />} path="/signup" />
    //   </Route>

    //   <Route element={<ErrorPage />} path="*" />

    // </Routes>
  )
};

export default observer(AppRouter);
```

Function checkAuth():

```
async checkAuth() {
        this.appStore.setLoading(true)
        try {

            this.userStore.setUser({
                nickname: 'igor',
                email: 'igorasdasda',
                id: 1,
                avatar: '',
                about: '',
                isOnline: true,
                onlineTime: ''
            });

            this.appStore.setAuth(true)
        }
        catch (e: any) {
            console.log(e.response.data)
        }
        finally {
            this.appStore.setLoading(false)
            console.log(this.userStore.getUser);
        }
    }
```

My state stores:

```
export class UserStore {
    constructor() { makeObservable(this) }

    @observable private user = {} as IUser

    @computed get getUser() {
        return this.user
    }
    
    @action  setUser(newUser: IUser) {
        this.user = newUser
    }
}
```

```
export class AppStore {
    constructor() { makeObservable(this) }

    // Loading state
    @observable private isLoading = false

    @computed get getIsLoading() {
        return this.isLoading
    }
    @action setLoading(value: boolean) {
        this.isLoading = value
    }

    // Auth state
    @observable private isAuth = false;

    @computed get getIsAuth() {
        return this.isAuth
    }
    @action setAuth(value: boolean) {
        this.isAuth = value
    }
}
```

Comment: useEffect without dependency array will be executed on every render, calling the function that causes a rerender... Why dont you have an empty dependency array as 2nd argument of useEffect if you want it to run only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `useEffect` should have the `controller` as the only dependency. like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    controller.checkAuth();
  }, [controller]);
```

With no dependency array (Like you did), the `useEffect` will trigger every render, which will cause another `checkAuth`, and you don't want that. Having the `controller` as your only dependency means that only if the reference of the controller changes (Which will not happen) the `useEffect` will run again.

Few more comments about your code:

1. In your stores, you don't have to create a `private` observable, a getter and a setter, like you did with `isLoading`. it's redundant. you just make the the field `public` without the setter and the getter.
2. I would avoid `export default`
3. It's better to put the `observer` on the function itself, while naming it (Better for the react dev tools), like this:
   `const AppRouter: FC = observer(function AppRouter() {`

Comment: Thank you very much for both answer and advices